# Two programs. exactly the same besides the sites its watching. but only one can be ran at a time. Both using the same Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

i assume only one program can connect to a mongodb at a time without extra coding? im running a monitor but only one runs. when i try to start the other i get this error

```js
Error: Cannot find module './drivers/node-mongodb-native'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\blake\Desktop\shopify monitor 2\shopify-monitor\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\blake\Desktop\shopify monitor 2\shopify-monitor\node_modules\mongoose\index.js
- C:\Users\blake\Desktop\shopify monitor 2\shopify-monitor\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:772:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\blake\Desktop\shopify monitor 2\shopify-monitor\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:15:27)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1095:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1124:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:816:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\blake\\Desktop\\shopify monitor 2\\shopify-monitor\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\blake\\Desktop\\shopify monitor 2\\shopify-monitor\\node_modules\\mongoose\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\blake\\Desktop\\shopify monitor 2\\shopify-monitor\\index.js'
  ]
}
```

im going to assume to avoid breaking a database you need extra code to connect to programs to the same database? or is this just being weird. again its the same program just copy pasted and replaced websites its watching which shouldent matter especially since they arent the same sites as the other monitor.

im doing this because when i try to run to many node cant handle all the requests and starts to fail so i need to spread the load out.

Comment: Have you run `npm install`?

Comment: yes i even did npm install --update aswell